# How to hide the scrollbar in wpf when the content fits the window?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, scrollview

How can i hide the scroll-bar if it's not enabled (when the content fits the window)?I've tried to use the is-enabled property but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have a `ScrollViewer` and you would like to only show the `Scrollbars` when they are needed?

In that case you can set:

```
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```